# Alfresco Creating a new user group that permits only creating user and groups

Tags: share, alfresco, authority

I want to create a **new user group**.

**The members in this user group can create new users and new groups.**

I think creating users or groups require `admin` permission. **This user group does not have other admin permission except creating, editing and deleting user,group.** Does alfresco provide this kind of group in alfresco community 4.0c? How can I implement it? How to add a new group with specified permission? I really appreciate for help.

Comment: I've not checked in detail, but I think you'll want to customise the build in permissions, and alter the spring beans to give a special group extra permissions. If no-one offers a detailed answer, I'd suggest you look into that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a custom role in `permissionDefinitions.xml` but I don't think that would help in this instance, since the ability to create users and groups plus the other administrative actions are hard-wired to the built-in administrators role.

Instead, you could create a custom web script which performs a check to see if the current user is a member of your custom security group. Since the authenticated user may not be a repository admin (and probably isn't) then you would need to use something like this [Sudo tool for Alfresco webscripts](http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2009/11/23/sudo-like-tool-for-alfresco-webscripts/) to temporarily give them permission to create the objects.

You would need to be competent in Java webscript development in order to implement this. There are some good resources on the Alfresco wiki, documentation and training materials available online.

Comment: We've managed in some other way though..we created a web-script with "runas" admin option. This webscript exposes only a basic UI where you can add users, create groups and add/remove users from groups.
it's not the best in security terms, but at least it works like a charm!

Comment: Yes, that would also work. The downside is that you then cannot detect within the web script who is making the request, since it will always run as the same user. The sudo-like extension gets round this by just applying the privilege escalation to the user/group creation operations.

Comment: Can't you alter `public-services-security-context.xml` and change the rules on who can call `PersonService.createPerson` (and the appropriate group) ?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thank for ur help. In public-services-security-context.xml, I don't know how to check for a new group.Can you give me some examples.

Comment: Did you take a look that Spring file? I believe Gagravarr is referring to the `PersonService_security` bean in that file, and it looks to me like you can specify a value such as `ACL_METHOD.GROUP_myGroupName` next to the methods that you wish to restrict to that security group. The default is `ACL_METHOD.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR`.

Comment: That might work at the permissions level, but aren't all the Share UIs for user/group management exposed only for admin? e.g. in `share-config.xml` the links in the header are hidden for non-admin. If you also customise so these are visible, it might work, but not sure if the user/group management pages also have built-in admin assumptions...

Comment: Yeah, my idea is to show user/group management exposed not only for admin but also for specified group by customizing share-config.xml with new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293331/customizing-surf-platform-root-scoped-api. If you have other idea, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You cane manage that through Alfresco Share. In your Alfresco installation directory:
`/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/model/permissionDefinitions.xml` you'll find the **permissionDefinitions.xml** file. Through that file you can manage your custom roles for Alfresco users and groups.
[Here, in this WIKI](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Permissions_in_Share) you can find some hints about what you need to change to accomplish that.
Hope it helps. The wiki helps here, if you need some better explanation please let me know.