# Webscript authentication

Tags: authentication, share, alfresco

In alfresco execution of webscript, we can define whether the webscript authentication. [Advanced Description Options](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#Authenticating)

But I want to know **"Is it a single webscript can be executed as admin or member of some group only modifying authentication property?"**

I want to write new programs for **member of some group, not member of admin group, can create new users, upload users and delete existing users**. All webscripts[*user-csv-upload.post, person.delete, people.post*] to do these tasks require **admin** authentication. If I changed to authentication of these webscripts to user and run these webscript as admin like `<authentication runas="admin">user</authentication>`. All normal users can create new users. **So I want to check that these webscript can only invoked one condition is met**.

If I cannot check, I have to do two ways.

1. I have to write the same logic to two different webscripts, one for admin and one for member of some group
2. write authentication checking inside controller file with [sudo like tool](http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2009/11/23/sudo-like-tool-for-alfresco-webscripts/) for current user is admin or member of some group.

I want to get any of your suggestion. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Solution:**

I found exact code for my needs in [sudo-like-tool-for-alfresco-security-aspects](http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2010/01/16/sudo-like-tool-for-alfresco-security-aspects/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Will Abson said in another question post, the most elegant solution is using this: [Sudo Tool for Alfresco WebScripts](http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2009/11/23/sudo-like-tool-for-alfresco-webscripts/). With this tool you can grant your user (if this users is part of a certain custom group) temporarily admin privileges. If not, it acts as a normal user with his own privileges. It requires some Java coding, though.

Otherwise, the solution number 1 is what we achieved for an our client. We developed a custom webscript with a custom url known only to their manager users, that can run script with "runas=admin" option, and make what they want. In this case, what you can do is: expose a link to the "user management webscript", **only** if the manager user is logged in, otherwise the link doesn't appear, and you respect some sort of "security". It's not very elegant but does the trick.

Comment: The earlier post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248734/alfresco-creating-a-new-user-group-that-permits-only-creating-user-and-groups) was actually by the same user. I agree it was answered already there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found exact code for what I need in http://fabiostrozzi.eu/2010/01/16/sudo-like-tool-for-alfresco-security-aspects/.