# Customizing Surf Platform Root-Scoped API

Tags: share, alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to customize [Surf Platform Root-Scoped API](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Freferences%2FAPISurfPlatform-intro.html) specifically **user** object. That means **add new property or method to user object to check the user is in certain group in `header.inc.ftl` [in share] like `<#if user.isAdmin>**

1. How can I implement this?
2. Is [Alfresco Root Scoped Objects](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#Root_Scope_Objects) can be used as Surf Platform Root-Scoped object?

I have no idea of customizing surf platform root object. Can anyone help me???

Comment: Why do you need to add a new property to the user object? Can you not just make a call back to the repository from the component you're modifying, in order to perform the is-admin check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the role security model is hardcoded in spring-surf/spring webscripts. There is guest, user and admin. If what you want is another analogous role you'll have to hack the spring-surf libaries, namely:

```
org/springframework/extensions/surf/mvc/PageView.java
org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/ScriptUser.java
org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/Description.java
org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/connector/User.java
```

This is what I had to do to implement `user.isEmployee`. This approach allows you to literally  treat your new role just as the others.

you can use

```
<authentication>employee</authentication>
```

in page descriptors or

```
<item type="link" permission="employee" id="people">/people-finder</item>
```

on the navigation.

Just checking whether the user is in a certain group in a certain webscript is a whole diffrent story and does not provide the same functionality.

If what you want is the latter, you should make a call to

```
/alfresco/service/api/groups/{shortName}
```

miss
and works through the response.

**Update:** The item permission attribute requires a little more tweaking.
In `header.get.js`, propagate the new role to it gets processed properly in `header.inc.ftl`:

```
model.permissions =
{
    guest: user.isGuest,
    admin: user.isAdmin,
    employee : user.isEmployee
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. now I can call user.isPartialAdmin in my ftl file like that ${user.isPartialAdmin?string} by adding a new method in ScriptUser.java and User.java. I also modify PageView.java and Description.java. But I can't write like permission="partialAdmin" in page descriptors. What am I wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: I don't think page-descriptors support a permission attribute. For page-descriptors (i.e. site-data/pages/repository.xml) use the authentication element as shown. The item element with the permission attribute shown is from share-config-custom.xml.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I mean <item type="link" id="people" permission="employee">/people-finder</item> in share-config-custom.xml. It does not show people finder whether use is employee or not. Let me know your idea..

Comment: I updated the answer with the missing tweak to get permission="employee" show the desired effect in the navigation.

Answer (score -1):

you could try (in JavaScript I managed something like) this:

```
user = Application.getCurrentUser(context);
       String userName = user.getUserName();
       user.isAdmin() >>> result return true if user logining is admin
```

or in JSP:

```
#{NavigationBean.currentUser.admin == true}
```

Sorry, i noticed now you was talking about Surf Platform root objects, but the link you put there, is deprecated for Alfresco versions above 3.3. You still use something so old?
If you manage to use JavaScript API's you could use "person" root object, with boolean isAdmin().

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.But I want to get in ftl file.

Comment: The question relates to Spring Surf, not to the JSF client. Furthermore the 'JavaScript API' you refer to is the repository JS API, which is not directly available inside Spring Surf. From Surf the only access you have to the repository is via its remote API.