# alfresco user creation rights to a non admin user

Tags: alfresco, administrator, creation

I work with alfresco 5.0.d
I want some users (who have a particular role) can create other user.
I don't want to add these users to the Administrators group.

I realize that the user can enter to create page (http://localhost:9090/share/page/console/admin-console/users) only if he is admin.

So how can I authorize a user with a particular role to enter the user management page? and create , delete or modify user ?

thank you

Comment: Probably duplicate:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248734/alfresco-creating-a-new-user-group-that-permits-only-creating-user-and-groups

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this,One way is too manipulation of permissions.But that will become more difficult.Instead of that do below things.

1.Create a webscript and pass required parameter for creating user.From that webscript create a user.

2.Create one dashlet or page in alfresco share and call the webscript, pass userName as parameter(along with the data of new user) and validate that user inside webscript(for identifying that user have access to create user or not).

Above approach is less secure.But if you don't have issue of confidentiality than you can go with that.If confidentiality is an issue.Than you need to find something which validates your user.Like creating another webscript which validates user.